# can I have a dictionary act as an attribute with a default return value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not sure that this is possible, but what I would like is to have a dictionary act as an attribute where it returns a default value when called.  Basically something along the lines of:

```
class galaxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mass = {'total':10,
                     'gas':2,
                     'stellar':8}

> gal = galaxy()

## call the dict like an attribute
> gal.mass
10

## but also have access to the dict
> gal.mass['total']
10
> gal.mass['gas']
2
```

*if* this can even be done, what would be the most efficient way to go about it?

Comment: Why would you do this?  You have a custom object here, just make mass a member and the dictionary another member.

Comment: You could give `galaxy` a property attribute that gives you the current value of `mass['total']`. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: It is possible to do this with a custom metaclass.

Comment: @AaronD: Consider: If `gal.mass` returns `gal.mass['total']` how do you refer to the`dict` itself?

Comment: I'm just trying to make things a bit cleaner for the end user.  For example, each galaxy has a number of different radii and rather than have a bunch of  properties (full_mass_radius, half_mass_radius, r200, r_virial, etc) I would love to have a dictionary-like object that allows for gal.radius to return a default value (say full_mass_radius), but give the user the option to pick a different radius such as gal.radius['r_virial'].

Answer (score 2):

The least surprising result for your end-user, I think, would come from providing an access method with an optional parameter, like so:

```
class galaxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mass = {'total':10,
                      'gas':2,
                      'stellar':8}
    def get_mass(self, body='total'):
        return self._mass[body]

gal = galaxy()
print gal.get_mass()
print gal.get_mass('gas')
```

Or, perhaps:

```
class galaxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mass = {'gas':2,
                      'stellar':8}
    def get_mass(self, body=None):
        if body is None:
            return sum(self._mass.values())
        return self._mass[body]
```